# HTML output replacing text once form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code. For some reason, the starred line is having a problem. Whenever I load the page, I get **/15** like I should. However, when I submit the html form, the output replaces the **/15**. Is there anyway to make the output come before the **/15** instead of replacing it?

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body class="mmmm">
<div class="center">

<script language="JavaScript">
function add(){   
    var rawScore=document.getElementById('rawScore');
    var apScore=document.getElementById('apScore');
    var mcPerc=document.getElementById('mcPerc');

    rawScore.value = 0;
    rawScore.value = Math.round(parseInt(mc.value)
                                + parseInt(one.value)*1.1538
                                + parseInt(two.value)*.9375
                                + parseInt(three.value)*1.25);
    mcPerc.value= Math.round(parseInt(mc.value)/60*1000)/10;
    if (rawScore.value>=73){
        apScore.value="5";
    }
    else if(rawScore.value>=57){
        apScore.value="4";
    }
    else if(rawScore.value>=49){
        apScore.value="3";
    }
    else if(rawScore.value>=38){
        apScore.value="2";
    }
    else{
        apScore.value="1";
    }
}
</script>




 <form class="bbbb" name="frmf">

    Multiple Choice Score:
    <input class="ddddd" type="number" id="mc" value="60" min="0" max="60"/>
    <FONT COLOR="474747">/60</FONT>

    <br/>
    Free Response 1 Score:
    <input class="aaaaa" type="number" id="one" value="13" min="0" max="13"/>
    <FONT COLOR="474747">/13</FONT>

    <br/>
    Free Response 2 Score: 
    <input class="aaaaa" type="number" id="two" value="8" min="0" max="8"/>
    <FONT COLOR="474747">/8</FONT>

    <br/>
    Free Response 3 Score: 
    <input class="aaaaa" type="number" id="three" value="6" min="0" max="6"/>
    <FONT COLOR="474747">/6</FONT>

    <br/>
    <p>
        <input type ="button" value="Calculate Score" onClick="add();"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        **AP Score:
        <output class="apScore" type="text" id="apScore"/> /15**
        <p>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Raw Score:
            <output class="rawScore" type="text" id="rawScore"/>
            <p>
                Multiple Choice Percent:
                <output class="mcPerc" type="text" id="mcPerc"/>
            </p>
        </p>
    </p>
</form>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please indent your code so it's more readable.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the corresponding closing tag to your `<output>` elements. Otherwise, due to a bug in the browser probably, it thinks that what is following it is the value:

```
**AP Score: <output class="apScore" type="text" id="apScore"></output> /15**
```

note that IE does not support `<output>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

what about `apScore.value = "3" + apScore.value;` ?
that would prepend "3" before the value which is it currently.
generally you could do `apScore.value="1" + "/15";` or even `apScore.value="1/15";`